# Multivariable calculus, using unit vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we want the derivative of $f(x,y)$ in the direction of $\langle 1,1\rangle$. We must convert this to a unit vector: $\langle 1/\sqrt2, 1/\sqrt2\rangle$ in order to use the formula. So I don’t find it intuitive that the partial $x$ must be multiplied by $1/\sqrt2$ and the partial $y$ must be multiplied by $1/\sqrt2$, take the sum, and that’s your derivative in the direction $\langle 1, 1\rangle$.

Comment: Would you rather report speeds in miles per hour or miles per 4.26435777 hours?

Comment: See a proof: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx

Comment: I do agree but why use a vector with magnitude 1? Why not 0.5? I completely see how directional derivative in direction <1,0> is simply 1*partial x. What I do not get is why for vector <a, b> the directional derivative is a* partial x + b* partial y.

Comment: because magnitude 1 gives you a direction, without altering the speed at which you're travelling in that direction.

Comment: This is the third time on the same day that you ask basically the same question...

Comment: Because no one will give an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative is the rate of change of your function at a given point when you move along the given direction. You want to find the linear change when you move in the given direction one unit of length. That is why you normalize your direction vector to make its length $1$.